# MVC login screen that validates with the servers windows users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

So here is my dilemma,
I want to use windows authentication but not in the traditional sense.
I need users to be able to provide me with a password for a pre-determined user. Which exists on the server where my IIS is running.
This user is a local user on that machine.

Setting MVC to windows authentication brings up that god awful pop-up window where you have to login. I want to show them a nice login window in the style of my Webapp.

So my solution to that was, use the individual account authentication.
Now that's also nice and dandy, but that uses EF and a database, and i don't want to save and maintain any passwords.

So i found this piece of code:

```
PrincipalContext context = 
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null);
return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

Which does what i want BUT. How do i then check if users are actually authenticated after they navigate to another page?

I've used the individual user accounts for another website and you can use [Authorize] as a way to do this. but i don't have an actual model to verify here.

Does someone have an idea on how i can solve this issue?
Or has someone run into a similar situation?

Also i understand there isn't a whole lot of code here, but quite honestly i couldn't get far enough to actually show you guys something worth posting.

EDIT:
Would a Session be the right way to go? i could set a session variable for the logged-in state and check that on each page? I'd prefer another method though. (Cookies are a no go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session should be the way to go.
Also, have you considered using external authentication? That way you won't need to maintain passwords. http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/enabling-login-from-external-sites-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site

Most likely you will need to use this guy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication(v=vs.110).aspx
Another link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Additionally you may take a look at `IAuthenticationManager` in the automatically generated `AccountController`, it has few interesting methods, see if you can reuse them.

```
//
        // Summary:
        //     Add information to the response environment that will cause the appropriate
        //     authentication middleware to grant a claims-based identity to the recipient
        //     of the response. The exact mechanism of this may vary.  Examples include
        //     setting a cookie, to adding a fragment on the redirect url, or producing
        //     an OAuth2 access code or token response.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   identities:
        //     Determines which claims are granted to the signed in user. The ClaimsIdentity.AuthenticationType
        //     property is compared to the middleware's Options.AuthenticationType value
        //     to determine which claims are granted by which middleware. The recommended
        //     use is to have a single ClaimsIdentity which has the AuthenticationType matching
        //     a specific middleware.
        void SignIn(params ClaimsIdentity[] identities);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Add information to the response environment that will cause the appropriate
        //     authentication middleware to grant a claims-based identity to the recipient
        //     of the response. The exact mechanism of this may vary.  Examples include
        //     setting a cookie, to adding a fragment on the redirect url, or producing
        //     an OAuth2 access code or token response.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   properties:
        //     Contains additional properties the middleware are expected to persist along
        //     with the claims. These values will be returned as the AuthenticateResult.properties
        //     collection when AuthenticateAsync is called on subsequent requests.
        //
        //   identities:
        //     Determines which claims are granted to the signed in user. The ClaimsIdentity.AuthenticationType
        //     property is compared to the middleware's Options.AuthenticationType value
        //     to determine which claims are granted by which middleware. The recommended
        //     use is to have a single ClaimsIdentity which has the AuthenticationType matching
        //     a specific middleware.
        void SignIn(AuthenticationProperties properties, params ClaimsIdentity[] identities);
```

Usage may likely to be like that:

```
var userIdentity = await CreateUserIdentityAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();

 AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
                new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, 
                userIdentity);
```